# JQuery selector in for loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, jquery-selectors

I have a table with checkboxes and textboxes. The checkboxes are disabled on pageload. Their ids are assigned using a for:each loop in my jsp. I want to enable the checkbox once their textbox on their corresponding row changes value. Here's my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
            $("#doctorName" + i).on('change', function(){
                    $("#rowCheck" + i).prop('disabled', false);
            });
        }
```

If I replace `$("#rowCheck" + i) with $("#rowCheck0"),` it enables the checkbox. I don't want to hardcode every checkbox id since i render an undetermined number of rows.

Comment: another question about the issue of event in a loop.

Comment: please read about closures

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/closures-in-javascript/ get help from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a better approach for your context.

Try,

```
 $("[id^='doctorName']").on('change', function(){
      var id = this.id;
      $("#rowCheck" + id.charAt(id.length - 1)).prop('disabled', false);
 });
```

Comment: Wow. I never thought that I'll get an answer this fast! Thank you sir! I just started learning JQuery and JavaScript btw.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to enclose the block in another function:

```
for (var index = 0; index < listSize; index++) {
   (function(i){
            $("#doctorName" + i).on('change', function(){
                    $("#rowCheck" + i).prop('disabled', false);
            });

    }(index)
}
```